# Using parent classes

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Ive tried searching for an answer, but I feel like I'm asking the wrong questions.

I'm trying to create a "base parent" class that I can use to split up my rules nicely and across multiple files.  The structure of the parent would be something like this:

```
.parent {
    .child {
        //some rules here 
    }
```

I then want to be able to import that parent and child class to help define further elements (using faux-syntax here)

```
 @[custom class name]:
.parent {
    //some rules
    .child {
        color: #000
    }
```

Then, using my custom class name, I can specify this as the parent of another selector, like:

```
@[custom class name] {
    .grand-child {
              background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

This would generate out the following rule

```
 .parent .child .grand-child {
     color: #000;
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this could be to create a mixin that uses the `@content` directive, like so:

```
@mixin selectors {
  .parent {
    .child {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, any time you want to nest something under `.parent .child`, you would write:

```
@include selectors {
  .grand-child {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Which would result in the following CSS output:

```
.parent .child .grand-child {
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Huh, it's almost like you read the answer this question was marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: @cimmanon Ah, I totally missed your comment on the original question. Oh well, now the answer is here too.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make use of the & selector.

If .grand-child is in another file, you could do something like this:

```
.grand-child{
    .parent .child & {
         color: #000;
    }
}
```

this will compile to

```
.parent .child .grand-child{
    color: #000;
}
```

Or are maybe you are also looking for the @extend possibility?

where you would add

```
.grand-child{
    @extend .parent .child;
    color: #000
}
```

This would get the style from .parent .child and add it to the grand-child, but only the styling, it will not change the selector above.